# Tomar valor y asignar a un radioGroup

Tags: c#, extjs

¿Cómo puedo tomar el valor de una consulta a un `radioGroup`?
 Actualmente tengo definido el `radioGroup` de esta manera:
el valor que almaceno en una tabla es el que se encuentra en `inputValue`:

```
var chkTipoRRT = new Ext.form.RadioGroup({ id: 'chkTipoRRT', width: 400, columns: 4,
    items: [
    { name: 'chkTipoRRT', boxLabel: 'Estandar', inputValue: 'Estandar', checked: true },
    { name: 'chkTipoRRT', boxLabel: 'Doc', inputValue: 'Doc' },
    { name: 'chkTipoRRT', boxLabel: 'Plus', inputValue: 'Plus' }]
});
```

Al momento de consultar la tabla que contiene mi valor (en este caso es "Plus") no sé cómo asignar ese valor a este mismo radioGroup y que me muestre el check correspondiente al valor.  Tengo esto por el momento pero no me funciona:

```
(result.chkTipoRRT) ? (chkTipoRRT.setValue('plus')) : (chkTipoRRT.setValue('Doc'));
```

Comment: estas usando asp.net mvc? de ser asi ese result es un objeto json que obtienes quizas invocando el action usando $.ajax

Comment: asi es esta es la función  function datosRecepcion(id) {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'remote.aspx',
            tiemeout: 10000,
            params: { opcion: 'getRecepcion', id: id },
            success: function(response) {
                var result = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                if (result.success) {
                    (result.chkTipoRRT) ? (chkTipoRRT.setValue('plus')) : (chkTipoRRT.setValue('Doc'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doy por valido que la invocacion a `remote.aspx` es correcta, ademas imagino esta pagina expone un webmethod de nombre `getRecepcion`, de ser asi podrias hacer que la respuesta sea el valor del radio que debe seleccionarse.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({ url: 'remote.aspx', tiemeout: 10000, params: { opcion: 'getRecepcion', id: id }}, 
                success: function(response) { 
                    var result = Ext.decode(response.responseText); 
                    if (result.success) { 
                        chkTipoRRT.setValue(result.chkTipoRRT); 
                    }
                });
```

en este caso `result.chkTipoRRT` deveria retornar Doc, Plus, etc

Para ver el valor que recibes podrias definir la linea

```
console.log(result.chkTipoRRT);
```

en el `success` y si usas el Developr Tools del browser, al cual accedes con F12, en la solapa `Console` ver el valor

Para asignar el valor podrias usar

```
var checkName = "chek" + result.chkTipoRRT
Ext.getCmp(checkName).setValue(true);
```

Comment: chkTipoRRT.setValue(result.chkTipoRRT);  me retorna el valor correcto, el detalle es mostrar en mi radioGrupo el checked: true y que me muestre solo la casilla con el valor seleccionado al traer ese valor de la consulta

Comment: edite la pregunta, analiza al final como se arma el nombre mas le prefijo "chek" para tener asi el name del radio que debes seleccionar

Answer (score 0):

Que tal encontré la solución qui esta para mostrar el valor primero modifique el radioGroup de esta manera:

```
var chkTipoRRT = new Ext.form.RadioGroup({ id: 'chkTipoRRT', disabled:true, width: 400, columns: 4,
        items: [
        { name: 'chekEstandar', id: 'chekEstandar', boxLabel: 'Estandar', inputValue: 'Estandar' },
        { name: 'chekDoc', id: 'chekDoc', boxLabel: 'Doc', inputValue: 'Doc' },
        { name: 'chekPlus', id: 'chekPlus', boxLabel: 'Plus', inputValue: 'Plus' },
        { name: 'chekPersonalizada', id: 'chekPersonalizada', boxLabel: 'Personalizada', inputValue: 'Personalizada'}]
    });
```

asigne  id y cambie nombre para identificar cada uno de los checks.

en la funcion al traer el valor de result lo maneje de esta manera:

```
 function datosRecepcion(id) {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'remote.aspx',
            tiemeout: 10000,
            params: { opcion: 'getRecepcion', id: id },
            success: function(response) {
                var result = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                if (result.success) {
                    var chkRRT = result.chkTipoRRT;
                    if (chkRRT == 'plus') { Ext.getCmp('chekPlus').setValue(true); }
                    if (chkRRT == 'estandar') { Ext.getCmp('chekEstandar').setValue(true); }
                    if (chkRRT == 'doc') { Ext.getCmp('chekDoc').setValue(true); }
                    if (chkRRT == 'personalizada') { Ext.getCmp('chekPersonalizada').setValue(true); }
                } else {
                    msg(result.msg, Ext.Msg.OK, Ext.Msg.WARNING);
                }
            },
            failure: function(result, request) {
                msg('Ocurri%oacute; un error en la aplicaci&oacute;n', Ext.Msg.OK, Ext.Msg.ERROR);
            }
        });
    };
```

el cual valida el valor de la consulta y de acuerdo al valor que se obtuvo se asigna el checked en true.